# split a table into five by values of a field

Tags: sql, split

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm faced with this question.

I have this field  called 'type' which consists of 5 different responses, 'A','B','C','D', 'E'.
And each of these can have a 'result', 'yes' or 'no'.

The table looks like this

```
id code type result  
1   100  A    no  
2   100  A    yes  
3   100  A    no  
4   100  B    yes  
5   100  B    yes  
6   500  B    yes  
7   500  B    yes  
8   200  A    yes  
9   200  A    yes  
10  100  C    no  
11  100  C    yes  
12  200  B    yes  
13  500  B    yes  
14  500  C    yes
```

with the max(id) being the most recent result for each type by code.

I'm interested in getting something like this,

Table for type A:
**code max(id)  result**
100     3       no
200     9       yes

Table for type B:
**code max(id)  result**
100    5        yes
500    13       yes

and so on (tables for the rest of the types).

I'm in need of your help!

Thanks,
Ioanna

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
 select code, max(id), result from table
group by code, result , type;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select your_table.* from your_table 
join (
    select max(ad) maxid from your_table
    group by type, result
) t on your_table.id = t.maxid
```

Answer (score 0):

A canonical way of doing this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.type = t.type and t2.code = t.code);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(type, code, id)` is often well-optimized in many databases.

The other common method is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, code order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```